# Why do these arrays give me a slightly different answer than this original c code?

Tags: arrays, c

Okay, I'm new so thank you in advance for the help. I'm trying to improve some code I did for a class as I lean arrays. Here is the old code, followed by the loop using arrays that I would like to use. The code is for credit card validation, and the sums are off by 2. I used this fictitious credit card number: 376323472524349 for my testing. Any idea what I have done wrong?

Old code I want to improve:

```
int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8;
c1 = ((get_card % 100) / 10) * 2;
c2 = ((get_card % 10000) / 1000) * 2;
c3 = ((get_card % 1000000) / 100000) * 2;
c4 = ((get_card % 100000000) / 10000000) * 2;
c5 = ((get_card % 10000000000) / 1000000000) * 2;
c6 = ((get_card % 1000000000000) / 100000000000) * 2;
c7 = ((get_card % 100000000000000) / 10000000000000) * 2;
c8 = ((get_card % 10000000000000000) / 1000000000000000) * 2;
```

What I've been trying (compiles, but the answer is slightly off):

```
int n = 10;
int c[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
    {
    c[i] = ((get_card % (n*10)) / n) * 2;
    n = n * 100;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: An `int` is not large enough for `n`.

Comment: The type `int` is a signed integer type, typically 32 bits, which means it can hold values from around minus two billion to plus two billion. Your multiplications will drive `n` over the plus two billion limit, and signed integer overflow leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The reason the results are different is

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I adjusted to unsigned long n = 10;

Comment: Maybe an `unsigned long long` instead. `unsigned long` is 32b on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  //  i < 7
        c[i] = 3763'234725'24349ull % (n * 10ull) / n * 2;  // upgrade to unsigned long long to over best possible range for modula operation
```